# UICollectionViewCell is not rounding corner

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell, cornerradius

Im trying to make the corner rounded, but when I use cornerRadius, and maskToBouds, it do not works

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
        cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return cell
    }
```

Cell:
[image: image 1]

Comment: Have you tried clipsToBound = true?

Comment: I have already tried ir man! No success

Comment: Have you tried giving clipsToBounds = true to the imageView ??

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the `cell's` `contentView's` `cornerRadius`, change the `cornerRadius` of the `cell` itself, i.e.

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 30
cell.clipsToBounds = true
```

Do set the `clipsToBounds` of `cell` to `true` like in the above code.

**Suggestion:**

In case you want to set the `cornerRadius` of each `cell` in the `collectionView`, instead of doing it in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method, do it in `awakeFromNib()` method of your custom `UICollectionViewCell`, i.e.

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

This is because, since the `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method is executed multiple times, it is kind of inefficient writing the layout code there.

Comment: It also worked, but the top corner still flat! Just like this: https://imgur.com/a/33vdu5k

Comment: Are you referring to the grey part? Is that the collectionView or the cell?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it in `willDisplay:forItemAt:`

e.g.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        cell.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

Comment: it worked man, but its not rounding as expected! I mean, the top part still flat!

Comment: set image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit